# Python: save pandas data frame to parquet file

Tags: python-3.x, hdfs, parquet

Is it possible to save a pandas data frame directly to a parquet file?
If not, what would be the suggested process?

The aim is to be able to send the parquet file to another team, which they can use scala code to read/open it. Thanks!

Comment: Is the other team using Spark or some other Scala tools? Loading CSV is Spark is pretty trivial

Comment: If you have `pyspark` you can do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/jiffyclub/905bf5e8bf17ec59ab8f#file-hdf_to_parquet-py)

Answer (score 73):

Pandas has a core function `to_parquet()`. Just write the dataframe to parquet format like this:

```
df.to_parquet('myfile.parquet')
```

You still need to install a parquet library such as `fastparquet`. If you have more than one parquet library installed, you also need to specify which engine you want pandas to use, otherwise it will take the first one to be installed (as in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html)). For example:

```
df.to_parquet('myfile.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
```

Comment: Running this in Databricks 7.1 (python 3.7.5) , I get _'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'toParquet'_

Comment: Well, that seems to be an easy one: there is no toParquet, no. It's to_parquet. Cheers!
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html

Answer (score 29):

## Yes pandas supports saving the dataframe in parquet format.

## Simple method to write pandas dataframe to parquet.

Assuming, `df` is the pandas dataframe. We need to import following libraries.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
```

First, write the dataframe `df` into a `pyarrow` table.

```
# Convert DataFrame to Apache Arrow Table
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df_image_0)
```

Second, write the `table` into `parquet` file say `file_name.parquet`

```
# Parquet with Brotli compression
pq.write_table(table, 'file_name.parquet')
```

## NOTE: parquet files can be further compressed while writing. Following are the popular compression formats.

- Snappy ( default, requires no argument)
- gzip
- brotli

Parquet with Snappy compression

```
 pq.write_table(table, 'file_name.parquet')
```

Parquet with GZIP compression

```
pq.write_table(table, 'file_name.parquet', compression='GZIP')
```

Parquet with Brotli compression

```
pq.write_table(table, 'file_name.parquet', compression='BROTLI')
```

#### Comparative comparison achieved with different formats of parquet

[image]

Reference:
https://tech.blueyonder.com/efficient-dataframe-storage-with-apache-parquet/

Comment: is this compression for only archive purposes? Can we use this compressed parquet file to build lets say a table ?

Answer (score 8):

There is a relatively early implementation of a package called fastparquet - it could be a good use case for what you need.

https://github.com/dask/fastparquet

```
conda install -c conda-forge fastparquet
```

or

```
pip install fastparquet

from fastparquet import write 
write('outfile.parq', df)
```

or, if you want to use some file options, like row grouping/compression:

```
write('outfile2.parq', df, row_group_offsets=[0, 10000, 20000], compression='GZIP', file_scheme='hive')
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible.  Here is example code:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=True)
pq.write_table(table, 'output.parquet')
```

Answer (score 4):

[pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html) has support for storing pandas dataframes:

```
import pyarrow

pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(dataset)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the approach that worked for me  - similar to the above - but also chose to stipulate the compression type:

set up test dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
```

convert data frame to parquet and save to current directory

```
df.to_parquet('df.parquet.gzip', compression='gzip')
```

read the parquet file in current directory, back into a pandas data frame

```
pd.read_parquet('df.parquet.gzip')
```

output:

```
    col1    col2
0    1       3
1    2       4
```

Comment: Why do we need to import when we don't use anything from it?

Answer (score 1):

**Pandas directly support parquet so-**

```
df.to_parquet('df.parquet.gzip', compression='gzip')
# this will convert the df to parquet format


df_parquet = pd.read_parquet('df.parquet.gzip')
# This will read the parquet file

df.to_csv('filename.csv')
# this will convert back the parquet to CSV
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, quite possible to write a `pandas dataframe` to the `binary parquet`
format. Some additional libraries are required like `pyarrow` and `fastparquet`.

```
import pyarrow 
import pandas as pd
#read parquet file into pandas dataframe
df=pd.read_parquet('file_location/file_path.parquet',engine='pyarrow')
#writing dataframe back to source file
df.to_parquet('file_location/file_path.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
```