# How to write parquet file from pandas dataframe in S3 in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, parquet

I have a pandas dataframe. i want to write this dataframe to parquet file in S3.
I need a sample code for the same.I tried to google it. but i could not get a working sample code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First ensure that you have pyarrow or fastparquet installed with pandas.

Then install boto3 and aws cli. Use aws cli to set up the config and credentials files, located at .aws folder.

Here is a simple script using [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html), and [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-examples.html) to create a temporary parquet file and then send to AWS S3.

Sample code excluding imports:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

def main():
    data = {0: {"data1": "value1"}}
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
    write_pandas_parquet_to_s3(
        df, "bucket", "folder/test/file.parquet", ".tmp/file.parquet")


def write_pandas_parquet_to_s3(df, bucketName, keyName, fileName):
    # dummy dataframe
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
    pq.write_table(table, fileName)

    # upload to s3
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    BucketName = bucketName
    with open(fileName) as f:
       object_data = f.read()
       s3.put_object(Body=object_data, Bucket=BucketName, Key=keyName)
```

Comment: Your example would have looked cleaner with the imports.  I also think you will get more points if you add a second example using BytesIO as a buffer.

Comment: import pyarrow as pa , import pyarrow.parquet as pq  is needed.

Comment: how would you write partitioned parquet?

Answer (score 61):

For your reference, I have the following code works.

```
s3_url = 's3://bucket/folder/bucket.parquet.gzip'
df.to_parquet(s3_url, compression='gzip')
```

In order to use `to_parquet`, you need `pyarrow` or `fastparquet` to be installed. Also, make sure you have correct information in your `config` and `credentials` files, located at `.aws` folder.

Edit: Additionally, `s3fs` is needed. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54006942/1862909

Comment: I have multiple profiles in my .aws/config and credentials files... is there a way to set which profile to use?   (I suppose setting my ENV var: AWS_PROFILE=<blah> would work, but would be nice to do it in code)

Comment: Yes, you first import `boto3`, then set your profile using `session = boto3.Session(profile_name={your_profile}")`

Comment: For completeness, if you want a `.parquet` as output file, drop the compression arg and change the file name to `.parquet`: `s3_url = 's3://bucket/folder/bucket.parquet'
df.to_parquet(s3_url)
`

Comment: Fully agree with ending filename as parquet, because .gzip implies you need to unzip it.
My comment is to warn of a caveat using to_parquet(...). If you use engine=fast_parquet and provide partition_cols, to_parquet leaves a trail of directory starting with "s3:" at your working dir. Be warned.

Answer (score 33):

the below function gets parquet output in a buffer and then write buffer.values() to S3 without any need to save parquet locally

Also, since you're creating an s3 client you can create credentials using aws s3 keys that can be either stored locally, in an airflow connection or aws secrets manager

```
def dataframe_to_s3(s3_client, input_datafame, bucket_name, filepath, format):

        if format == 'parquet':
            out_buffer = BytesIO()
            input_datafame.to_parquet(out_buffer, index=False)

        elif format == 'csv':
            out_buffer = StringIO()
            input_datafame.to_parquet(out_buffer, index=False)

        s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=filepath, Body=out_buffer.getvalue())
```

S3_client is nothing but a boto3 client object.Hope this helps!

courtesy- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615630/12036254

Comment: For anyone wondering what is input_dataframe.to_parquet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066582/python-save-pandas-data-frame-to-parquet-file

Comment: For data having timestamp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53893554/transfer-and-write-parquet-with-python-and-pandas-got-timestamp-error

Comment: I followed this and got garbage values written in the file. :( What could be going wrong?

Comment: @gurjarprateek, it seems some of data is being lost even though I'm not seeing any errors. At first I believe to be lack of memory (DFS ares somewhat large), but I'd expect a error message

Comment: @LucasAbreu this could happen if the size of data is greater than system memory

Comment: Is there a way to specify the compression scheme in this?

Comment: @khan you can modify the function to add compression. by default it uses snappy compression 
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html#pandas-dataframe-to-parquet

Comment: Oh yes, I see..totally missed it.

Answer (score 13):

For python 3.6+, AWS has a library called [aws-data-wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler) that helps with the integration between Pandas/S3/Parquet

to install do;

```
pip install awswrangler
```

if you want to write your pandas dataframe as a parquet file to S3 do;

```
import awswrangler as wr
wr.s3.to_parquet(
    dataframe=df,
    path="s3://my-bucket/key/my-file.parquet"
)
```

Comment: Caveat: unlike `pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet()`, wrangler has no option to pass kwargs to the underlying parquet library. This means that you can't set lower-level options if you need to. I ran into this issue when PyArrow failed to infer the table schema-- in pandas, you can work around this by [explicitly defining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66805787/4212158) a PyArrow schema

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide a further example using kwargs to force an overwrite.

My use case is that the partition structure ensures that if I reprocess an input file the output parquet should overwrite whatever is in the partition. To do that I am using kwargs passed through to pyarrow:

```
s3_url = "s3://<your-bucketname>/<your-folderpath>/"
df.to_parquet(s3_url, 
              compression='snappy', 
              engine = 'pyarrow',
              partition_cols = ["GSDate","LogSource", "SourceDate"],
              existing_data_behavior = 'delete_matching')
```

That last argument (existing_data_behaviour) is part of **kwargs passed through to underlying pyarrow write_dataset. (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset)

Without that a rerun would create duplicate data. As noted above, this requires `s3fs`