# Transfer and write Parquet with python and pandas got timestamp error

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I tried to concat() two parquet file with pandas in python .
It can work , but when I try to write and save  the Data frame to a parquet file ,it display the error :

```
 ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[ns] to timestamp[ms] would lose data:
```

I checked the doc. of pandas, it default the timestamp syntax in ms when write the parquet file.
How can I white the parquet file with used schema after concat?
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

table1 = pd.read_parquet(path= ('path.parquet'),engine='pyarrow')
table2 = pd.read_parquet(path= ('path.parquet'),engine='pyarrow')

table = pd.concat([table1, table2], ignore_index=True) 
table.to_parquet('./file.gzip', compression='gzip')
```

Comment: it seems that parquet only supports ms and pandas is working with ns. Did you try working with `from_pandas` and `to_pandas` as suggested [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html)?

Comment: @hansaplast Hello mate ,yes I already tried the suggestion with the doc. ,but I thought the reason made it can't be work was I wrote the wrong syntax with the function.   pd.Timestamp (np.datetime64[ns])

Comment: pandas needs to expose some options to permit unsafe casts or writing int96 nanosecond timestamps to Parquet. Can you open an issue with pandas?

Comment: Pandas forwards most keyword given to `to_parquet` to the given engine. This problem in particular can be solved with `table.to_parquet(allow_truncated_timestamps=True)`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Pandas already forwards unknown kwargs to the underlying parquet-engine since at least `v0.22`. As such, using `table.to_parquet(allow_truncated_timestamps=True)` should work - I verified it for pandas `v0.25.0` and pyarrow `0.13.0`. For more keywords see [the pyarrow docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter.html).

Comment: When I load the parquet file from S3 using read_parquet(), and Pyarrow engine I get the datetime field as string. I'd like to get the data frame back with a datetime column.

Comment: just a update - For me along with this option also had to set coerce_timestamps  ='ms'

Answer (score 20):

Thanks to @axel for the [link to Apache Arrow documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter.html):

> **allow_truncated_timestamps** (bool, default False) – Allow loss of data when coercing timestamps to a particular resolution. E.g. if
> microsecond or nanosecond data is lost when coercing to ‘ms’, do not
> raise an exception.

It seems like in modern Pandas versions we can pass parameters to `ParquetWriter`.

The following code worked properly for me (Pandas 1.1.1, PyArrow 1.0.1):

```
df.to_parquet(filename, use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True)
```

Comment: So this worked for me but just feels wrong... can someone point me to here's the right way to do this without using a deprecated timestamp :)

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a bug and you should do what Wes says. However, if you need working code now, I have a workaround.

The solution that worked for me was to specify the timestamp columns to be millisecond precision. If you need nanosecond precision, this will ruin your data... but if that's the case, it may be the least of your problems.

```py
import pandas as pd

table1 = pd.read_parquet(path=('path1.parquet'))
table2 = pd.read_parquet(path=('path2.parquet'))

table1["Date"] = table1["Date"].astype("datetime64[ms]")
table2["Date"] = table2["Date"].astype("datetime64[ms]")

table = pd.concat([table1, table2], ignore_index=True) 
table.to_parquet('./file.gzip', compression='gzip')
```

Comment: This `table1["Date"].astype("datetime64[ms]")` didn't work, still had `datetime64[ns]`. pandas 0.24.2

Answer (score 4):

I experienced a similar problem while using `pd.to_parquet`, my final workaround was to use the argument `engine='fastparquet'`, but I realize this doesn't help if you need to use PyArrow specifically.

Things I tried which did not work:

- @DrDeadKnee's workaround of manually casting columns `.astype("datetime64[ms]")` did not work for me (pandas v. `0.24.2`)
- Passing `coerce_timestamps='ms'` as a kwarg to the underlying parquet operation did not change behaviour.

Comment: I'm facing this issue with `fastparquet` and Presto backed by AWS Glue. Getting JDBC error. What was your solution to casting from `ns` to `ms` using `fastparquet`?

Answer (score 4):

I experienced a related order-of-magnitude problem when writing dask DataFrames with datetime64[ns] columns to AWS S3 and crawling them into Athena tables.

The problem was that subsequent Athena queries showed the datetime fields as year >57000 instead of 2020. I managed to use the following fix:

`df.to_parquet(path, times="int96")`

Which forwards the kwarg `**{"times": "int96"}` into fastparquet.writer.write().

I checked the resulting parquet file using package parquet-tools. It indeed shows the datetime columns as INT96 storage format. On Athena (which is based on Presto) the int96 format is well supported and does not have the order of magnitude problem.

Reference: https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/blob/master/fastparquet/writer.py, function `write()`, kwarg `times`.
(dask 2.30.0 ; fastparquet 0.4.1 ; pandas 1.1.4)

Comment: If you have multiple engines, make sure to pass `engine='fastparquet'` as well in the `to_parquet` method.

Comment: Indeed. If you have `pyarrow` and `fastparquet` installed, I think pyarrow takes precedence. Pyarrow does not recognize the `times` kwarg.