# How to specify AWS organization while writing a dataframe to s3 bucket

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, dataframe, amazon-s3, credentials

I want to write a pandas dataframe to my s3 bucket with the following method:

```
df.to_parquet(s3_bucket_url)
```

However, this method will use my default AWS credentials. I have multiple profiles in my AWS credentials and I would like to know how to specify the one I want to use when I am calling the methode df.to_parquet.

Thanks

Comment: How are you generating s3_bucket_url? Is it just `s3://bucket/folder/file.gz`? See if the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53502445/271415) help.

Comment: s3_bucket_url = 's3://bucketbbr/test' But I think that my problem comes from my jupyter notebook. I am using awsume to select the organization I am working in but then from jupyter notebook, df.to_parquet still want to use my default AWS profile. And by executing python script I don't have the problem any more. The question now is why  do I have this problem form Jupyter notebook. For information I am working with Windows 10.