# How to efficiently save a large pandas.Dataframe with million even billion rows with no error?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, hdf5

How to save a large Dataframe to disk with good reading speed?

I have a large datasets (youtube 8M), now I have extract the raw data to dict. And I want to save it as dataframe for reading by index with pytorch dataset.

For concrete, the validate data seems like this:

```py
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1112356 entries, 0 to 1112355
Data columns (total 4 columns):
id            1112356 non-null object
mean_rgb      1112356 non-null object
mean_audio    1112356 non-null object
label         1112356 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 42.4+ MB
```

The dtypes is listed below:

```py
id : str
mean_rgb : numpy.ndarray
mean_audio : numpy.ndarray
label :  numpy.ndarray
```

I want to save it to disk, for the purpose that I could efficiently read it.
First, I used the `hdf5` with `pd.to_hdf()`, but I got an `OverFlowError`.

And then, I turn to `csv` with successful saving. However, when I read data from this `.csv`, I get a corrupt `dataframe`. Where the rows is greatly more than **1112356**.

Finally, I saved the `dataframe` to `csv` with `chunksize=1000`, the reading result is still wrong with `2842137` rows as well as more confusing inner data.

```
RangeIndex: 2842137 entries, 0 to 2842136
Data columns (total 1 columns):
widwmean_rgbwmean_audiowlabel    object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 21.7+ MB
```

Comment: Maybe this link might help you: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d

Comment: `feather` perhaps may help

Answer (score 1):

I used the parquet file format to save my dataframe (4 million rows), saving as csv the output weighs more than 500MB, using a compressed parquet file I get a 7MB file. This is my code based on answers in [Python: save pandas data frame to parquet file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066582/python-save-pandas-data-frame-to-parquet-file):

```
import pandas as pd

df = your_dataframe 
df.to_parquet('tb.parquet', compression='gzip')
```

To read the exported file you can use this code:

```
pqt = pd.read_parquet('tb.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
```

The parquet file can be imported without problems in Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

Joblib and klepto python packages might help you.

On other hand, you do chunking store at-max you can in one chunk while storing and load iteratively and merge at the end.