# Load data frame as parquet file to Google cloud storage

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-storage

I have a dataframe created with pandas library which to be uploaded into Google cloud storage as a parquet file. Can anyone throw some light on how to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far and which parts are unclear ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: save pandas data frame to parquet file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066582/python-save-pandas-data-frame-to-parquet-file)

Comment: At this Google's documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet you can see how to do this