# Can i read and write a data binary file into apache parquet file format

Tags: python-3.x, compression, parquet, binaryfiles

I am trying to see if i can use apache parquet to convert a bunch of data binary file into parquet binary format and back to original data binary to get a better compression ratio compare to current gzip.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

with open('/tmp/799.module','rb') as f:   
    data=f.read()
print(len(data)) #approximately 500k lines
df=pd.DataFrame({'799.module':data},index=list(range(len(list(data)))))
table=pa.Table.from_pandas(df,preserve_index=False)
pq.write_table(table,'799.parquet')
df1=(pq.read_table('799.parquet')).to_pandas()
df2=df1["799.module"].values
print(df2)
f2=open('799.module','wb')
f2.write(df2)
f2.close
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59540258/706456) will be relevant. When calling `pq.write_table` you can pass a `compression` option and pass a different compressor. There are [several compressors](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/54e6133e887a6ea90501ddd72fff5312b7038a7c/src/main/thrift/parquet.thrift#L461) to choose from like GZIP, ZSTD, Snappy etc.